# ViewModel as parameter on fragment constructor

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I Have Fragment A that calls Fragment B or Fragment C. 
B and C uses a ViewModel provided by A.

For while, I'm passing the View as parameter on constructor:

- FragmentB(val viewModel: ViewModel)
- FragmentC(val viewModel: viewModel)

But this way, not is a good solution, because the app is crashing when try to reopen the fragment.

> Could not instantiate the fragment

What the best way to do this?

I thought create a newInstance method and pass the viewModel as argument on Bundle, but how I would transform this viewModel in Parcelable or Serializable?

Comment: See #4 in https://proandroiddev.com/the-seven-actually-10-cardinal-sins-of-android-development-491d2f64c8e0

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to create custom `Fragment` constructor which is not allowed in Android. 
I assume your `ViewModel` was created inside of fragment `A` using method

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this)
```

`ViewModel` created this way should be used only inside of this fragment(It won't crash if you i.e. pass it through `Object` or Singleton but it's not supposed to be used that way).

Better solution is to put all of these fragments `A`, `B`, `C` inside one activity.
This way you can call

```
ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity())
```

and get the same instance of the `ViewModel` in all of the fragments. So if you get the `ViewModel` using this method in your fragment `A`, put there some values and then replace fragment `A` with fragment `B` in the same activity, you can call `ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity())` again get access to the same instance of your `ViewModel` and retrieve the values.